# Analysing solution (.sol) file in pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, cplex, pyomo

I have a model in pyomo in say machine 1 and I have the CPLEX solver in machine 2. I convert the pyomo model (`ConcreteModel`) into a `problem.lp` file with function `model.write("problem.lp")` in machine 1. Then I transfer this file to machine 2 and get the `solution.sol` file from the CPLEX solver. But names of the variables in the solution file is different from the names of the variables of the model.

This is causing a problem in analysis of the solution.

Is there any way to convert or map the names of the variables in solution file to that of the model?

Thanks.

Edit 1: I think it boils down to finding the symbol map when the model is written. The symbol map id is returned by `model.write("problem.lp")` (see [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/PyomoGallery/blob/master/asl_io/write.py)). Now the question is I have the symbol map id. How do I get the symbol map file and use it to decode the variables in `solution.sol` file?

Comment: I suspect that the names in the `problem.lp` file are already different than the names in the pyomo model. Is that correct? And, I would expect that the names in the `solution.sol` file match those in the `problem.lp` file. If you look at the pyomo [source code](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/solvers/plugins/solvers/CPLEX.py), there is a `process_soln_file` method that looks like it does exactly what you're looking for. I am not a pyomo expert, and I have no idea if you can somehow utilize this functionality outside of a regular solve.

Comment: @rkersh, yes, you are right about the names in the `problem.lp` file to be similar to the names in `solution.sol` file but being different from the variable names in the pyomo model itself. I will have a look at the function you are referring to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As given in the Edit 1 the symbol map is returned while writing the model to `problem.lp`.
As given in line numbers 27-29 of [this code](https://github.com/Pyomo/PyomoGallery/blob/master/asl_io/write.py), a tuple of variable names in the model and its reference variable can be obtained.

Then, the XML file which the CPLEX generates (`solution.sol`) can be parsed in python using package like xml. Now we have the map and also the values. We just need to compare the reference variables and store its value into the variable with the name as that in the model.