# How to use pyomo to load *.sol file

Tags: pyomo

I use pyomo to write the script, but use external solver to do the optimization.

The external solver return a `*.sol` file. My question is that if pyomo or any package of python can decode the sol file, and pass the decision variable result into the original model. Therefore, we can do some post analysis.

Comment: You need to atleast try to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: There is a SOL reader in Pyomo, and a generic interface to ASL-compliant solvers.  Hence, this capability may already be available in the manner you desire by simply calling your solver from Pyomo.  If not, then you would need to call the SOL reader directly and load the data into the model yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add this as a comment but I dont have enough reputation.

I was facing a similar problem with CPLEX. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183842/analysing-solution-sol-file-in-pyomo) question. You have to basically store the variable map and use it while parsing the solution file. In my case CPLEX gives solution in XML format, so I used XML parser.

Hope this helps!