# Pyomo and IBM Decision Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, pyomo

I am trying to solve a pyomo model in the [docloud](https://pypi.org/project/docloud/) and import the results back into the model.

What is the easiest way to load an sol file via pyomo? So far I could not figure out how to do this at all. I already tried the [read](https://github.com/Pyomo/PyomoGallery/blob/master/asl_io/read.py)/[write](https://github.com/Pyomo/PyomoGallery/blob/master/asl_io/write.py) examples from the gallery without any luck.
I am have tried to do the following:

```py
_,sym_id = model.write("/tmp/problem.mps")
client.execute(input=["/tmp/anrochte.mps"], output="/tmp/result.xml")
```

Then I assume I nead to use a ReaderFactory to get a result which I then can import back into my model:

```py
with ReaderFactory(ResultsFormat.sol) as reader:
        results = reader("/tmp/result.xml", suffixes=[".*"])
results._smap = model.solutions.symbol_map[sym_id]
model.solutions.load_from(results)
```

However, afterwards all my variables in the model still have their default values.

Comment: Not an answer, but here are similar questions. One of them states that `.sol` files are `xml` files that can be handled directly in Python. Here are the links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399238/how-to-use-pyomo-to-load-sol-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183842/analysing-solution-sol-file-in-pyomo

Comment: Thanks! It seems in fact, that the .sol file can also not be an xml, but what the docloud spits out definetly is one. I am a bit confused about the file format for now.

Answer (score 0):

Alright it seems there is no straight forward way to do this within pyomo, but the json file from docloud is easy enough to parse. I am using the following for now:

```py
_,sym_id = model.write("/tmp/problem.mps")
resp = client.execute(input=["/tmp/problem.mps"], output="/tmp/result.json")

with open("/tmp/result.json") as f:
    res_json = json.load(f)

sym_map = model.solutions.symbol_map[sym_id]  
for var in res_json['CPLEXSolution']['variables']:
    sym_map.getObject(var["name"]).value = float(var["value"])
```

I am not sure what the "index" entry of for each variable means though.